# How to generate already modified reports in python

Tags: python, html, css, pandas

I write a program in python that generates 5 reports. One of them is just text and the rest is a data frame. Right now my reports have a really simple design(basic). I need to modify the program to give user ready report that looks good and clear. In 4 of them, I need to add some text before df. The text should be formatted, just like my df. I try to do it using HTML, but I have a problem. I don't know how to modify a table. I wanted to use `<style>` to make some modifications but there is a problem. First I will show you my code:

```
html = f'''

    <html>
    
        <head>
        
            <title>Knury Hodowlane</title>
            
        </head>
        <style type="text/css">
          table
          {
            width: 75%
            height:100px;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 15px auto 15px auto;
            background-color: white;
            -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
            -moz-border-radius: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 50px grey;
            -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 50px grey;
            -webkit-box-shadow:5px 5px 50px grey;
        }
        </style>

        
        <body>
            <div><img src='krowa-iz.jpg' width ="170" alt="" style="float:left;"></div>
            <h1><b><center>INSTYTUT ZOOTECHNIKI</center></b></h1>
            <p><h1><b><center>PAŃSTWOWY INSTYTUT BADAWCZY</center></b></h1></p>
            <h3><b><center>ZAKŁAD HODOWLI TRZODY CHLEWNEJ</center></b></h3>
            <p></p>
            <h3><p><b><center>EKSPERTYZA NR ......</center></b></p></h3>
            <p><center>W ZAKRESIE REKOMENDACJI DO BRAKOWANIA TZW "MINUS WARIANTÓW" Z POŚRÓD KNURÓW STADNYCH POD WZGLĘDEM ZBIORCZEJ WARTOŚCI HODOWLANEJ (<span style="color: red">ZWH</span>)</center></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <h3><p>RANKING KNURÓW STADNYCH POD WZGLĘDEM <span style="color: red">ZWH</span> (ROSNĄCO)</p></h3>
            {knuryDF.to_html()}
            
        </body>
    </html>
    '''
with open('raport_html.html','w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

In my code I use `f'''`, I need it to insert my data frame, but in this case, my code between `table` and `</style>` is no longer text and gonna generates an error. My code in style -> table is random I just wanted to check if this gonna work. Is any way to do it right? Maybe is a much better solution that I don't know. My report doesn't need to be an HTML file. In the beginning, I wanted to write it in excel but I don't know how.
Any help will be great. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi, this might help: https://linlinzhao.com/tech/2021/01/20/jinja-report.html